# HTML Text Editor - Simple Code

Tags: javascript

I want to create a very simple HTML toolbar that can do bold, italics and underline so when users select a content editable area within the html page that they can change the default text. Been doing loads of looking around on the internet but all i can find is jquery's with a million lines of code and i really don't want to use these as a lot of the code will be redundant.

Anyone know the code / know where i can get the code that is short and sweet and to the point

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below a simplest sample for ContentEditable. For documentation see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.execCommand

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Contenteditable simplest sample</title>
</head>
<body>

<button id="bold">b</button>
<button id="italic">i</button>
<button id="underline">u</button>
<div contenteditable="true">
Textinput here
</div>

<script>

document.getElementById("bold").onclick = function(e) {
 document.execCommand("bold", false, "");
};

document.getElementById("italic").onclick = function(e) {
 document.execCommand("italic", false, "");
};

document.getElementById("underline").onclick = function(e) {
 document.execCommand("underline", false, "");
};

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Greetings

Axel

Answer (score 0):

Could be done with [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) using the addClass & removeClass Method
Something like this would be all the code you need:
    `$( *YourTextElement* ).addClass( "YourCssDefinition" );`

This will of course only affect the entire text within the defined *YourTextElement*

 
....